C++20 Modules: Which information is actually exported
Since Cmake and MSVC has dropped the experimental support on C++20 modules, I'm trying to give it a shot right now.
The challenge for me is that our code must be backwartds compatible with classic includes.
So as a start i used templated set of classes which allready contained all implementations in the header.
I have been following this instructions:
https://www.kitware.com/import-cmake-the-experiment-is-over/
My actual module (ModuleLogger.cxx) looks like this
// Global module fragment where #includes can happen
module;

#include "LoggerTask.hpp" //< includes IMutex.hpp

// first thing after the Global module fragment must be a module command
export module LoggerTask;


export namespace t::logger
{
  using t::logger::Sink;
  using t::logger::SingleDebugMessage;
  using t::logger::DebugQueue;
  using t::logger::LoggerTask;
}

LoggerTask.hpp does include some files like IMutex.hpp which add some custom concepts (IMutex in that case)
IMutex.hpp looks like this
#pragma once
#include <concepts>
namespace t::interfaces
  template<typename T>
  concept IMutex_T = requires (T a) {  
    { a.lock() } -> std::same_as<void>;
    { a.try_lock() } -> std::same_as<bool>;
    { a.unlock() } -> std::same_as<void>;
  };
} //t::interfaces

However in my source I need to include IMutex.hpp as well for backwards compatibility issues
mySource.cpp
import LoggerTask;  //< Module has internally included the IMutex.hpp
#include <IMutex.hpp>  //< Needed for backwards compatibility
//some code

Now please correct me if I'm wrong, but i thought that named modules will only export the namespace t::logger
and the definitions of
t::logger::Sink;
t::logger::SingleDebugMessage;
t::logger::DebugQueue;
t::logger::LoggerTask;

(i.e. not the definition of IMutex).
However when I'm compiling mySource.cpp I'm getting some multiple type redefinition errors of IMutex.
Are all type definitions implicitly exported be modules? I thought this is exactly the benefits of modules that I could select what types/namespaces to export?
thx for your clarification guys :)

MSVC has trouble with mixing import and #include. The compiler team is working on improving the situation.
